# Vertical text recognition with VNRecognizeTextRequest

Tags: swift, ocr, vision

During some tests on a iOS app (written in Swift 5) I’m working on I found problems with the recognition of text written vertically with VNRecognizeTextRequest. I also examined the modifiable parameters of VNRecognizeTextRequest but nothing considers the recognition of vertical texts.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, upside-down text and vertical text are only readable if the recognitionLevel for the instance of VNRecognizeTextRequest is set to **.accurate** (rather than .fast).

If the increased processing time of recognitionLevel = .accurate is a problem, you might set .usesLanguageCorrection = false, though I wouldn't recommend that. Better is to reduce the size of the regionOfInterest, if you have some notion where the text will be located.

Maybe you've already solved this problem in the year (!) since you posted, in which case I'm curious whether you were able to complete your project.